# How to find the first git commit introducing a specific string?

Tags: git

Supposedly, I have a very simple repository with only `master` branch, consisting of `N` commits:

`1---2---3 ... -N (master)`

I know that one of the commits implements a specific feature, which in source code is reflected by adding a new string `MY_FEATURE` (e.g. a `C` macro/define). What is the simplest/fastest way to find this *first* commit? It must be mentioned the string is not present in the git log message/description (i.e. `git log` is not enough). I need a solution that would scale well for big repositories (e.g. Linux kernel).

Comment: `git log --oneline -S <MY_FEATURE>` can list all the commits that contains the string `<MY_FEATURE>`.

Comment: @ElpieKay that's easier than I thought! Git is awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(not sure at all if my answer really fits)</sup>

Perhaps you could use [git bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) using a shell script doing the relevant `grep` command as the testing command.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Basile! I'll give it a try.